# Grepping password and salt in database entry

Tags: bash, grep

If I have:

```
(1, 'username', '9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826', 'VdJt1S6R', 'z7WHG1tHg9cDWY9VWKawOu2b2KKyPkQji7oXghdhL68ZIqrTzn')
```

How do I get the format to be like:

```
9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826:VdJt1S6R
```

I need to use grep to do this, and there will be more than one database entry.

Comment: You might be better off using a parser.  What's the format that you're trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU grep to get require information from input, but it will be hard to re-organise it as `9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826:VdJt1S6R`

```
grep -Po "(?<=username',).*(?='[^']*')" file

 '9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826', 'VdJt1S6R',
```

With other tools, such as `awk/sed`, it can generate the format you expect, but seems you fix on grep command only.

Comment: This hard-codes the string `'username',` in the lookahead; if you need a generic solution, that won't be acceptable.

Comment: It is case by case solution. Otherwise, this will be no end discussion if follow you. Such as , if the required information is not at column 4 or 6 (such as below awk solution and yours), there are too much unknown conditions, which I don't think I need take care all of them.

Comment: Hmmmm, here I was thinking maybe this one input line is reasonably representative, but just one example out of many possible inputs. If it's just this one, why solve it programmatically at all? But yes, the OP should post a lot more details in order for us to be able to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

This one's going to to be really cumbersome with `grep` alone.  I'd probably go with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F "'" '{printf "%s:%s\n", $4, $6}'
```

This is using `'` as a field separator, so makes strong assumptions about the input data.

```
$ echo "(1, 'username', '9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826', 'VdJt1S6R', 'z7WHG1tHg9cDWY9VWKawOu2b2KKyPkQji7oXghdhL68ZIqrTzn')" | awk -F "'" '{printf "%s:%s\n", $4, $6}'
9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826:VdJt1S6R
$
```

---

Alternatively you might consider using just pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) statements, given that you have a limited toolset.  Something like:

```
while IFS=", " read -a A; do echo "${A[2]//\'}:${A[3]//\'}"; done
```

This reads lines one-by-one from the stdin, into an array `A`, and separating on `,`.  For each line, it echoes the fields you want in the format you want, removing `'` characters:

```
$ echo "(1, 'username', '9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826', 'VdJt1S6R', 'z7WHG1tHg9cDWY9VWKawOu2b2KKyPkQji7oXghdhL68ZIqrTzn')" | \
> while IFS=", " read -a A; do echo "${A[2]//\'}:${A[3]//\'}"; done
9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826:VdJt1S6R
$
```

---

If you must use `grep`, you'll probably need other tools too.  For example, you can pull out the information you need with `grep`, and then format it with `tr`:

```
$ echo "(1, 'username', '9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826', 'VdJt1S6R', 'z7WHG1tHg9cDWY9VWKawOu2b2KKyPkQji7oXghdhL68ZIqrTzn')" | \
> grep -oE "[[:xdigit:]]{32}', '[^']{8}" | \
> tr -s ", '" :
9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826:VdJt1S6R
$
```

Answer (score 0):

To suggest a slightly different tack, the following will reformat your wacky input to colon-delimited;

```
sed "s/^(//;s/'*, '*/:/g;s/')$//" wackyfile
```

For portability, I put `'*` instead of the more correct `'\?` because some `sed` dialects don't support that, and some others require you to omit the backslash. The `*` quantifier works the same everywhere. If your `sed` supports the `-r` option, you might want to use that, and adjust the regex accordingly.

Now, you can just pipe to `cut -d: -f3-4` to obtain the two fields you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk -F\' '{print $4":"$6}' file
9787b9f43503ef4a5264865a97beb826:VdJt1S6R
```